# Insert a reference to another cell programatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I think this should be simple, but I have searched stackoverflow and the Spreadsheet Service documentation and cannot find a way to do it.

I have a spreadsheet with an app-script. The spreadsheet has a summary sheet and multiple data sheets. On the summary sheet, I need to reference cells on the data sheet, using formulas like:

```
[='DataSheet1'!C10], [='DataSheet1'!C11], [='DataSheet1'!C12]
[='DataSheet2'!C10], [='DataSheet2'!C11], [='DataSheet2'!C12]
...etc
```

Do I have to build these formulas programatically using string concatenation, or is there a better way?

Ideally I would like to just specify a source and destination range of the same size and have the references created automatically

Comment: The formulas aren't clear. Are you using `[...]` to denote a cell and , to denote column separation? Do you know how to write a formula by using a script?

Comment: Sorry its not clear, the orientation is not important here. Say I have a cell, A1, and I want to use a script to insert the formula `='DataSheet1'!A10`. Do I have to build that formula using string concatenation, and then use `range.setFormulas()` or is there an easier way?